# How do I know when CreateProcess actually started a process?

Tags: winapi, createprocess, waitforsingleobject

I'm having trouble which boils down to wishing `CreateProcess` were `StartProcess`. The trouble is that there are circumstances under which `CreateProcess` returns true when it **created** the process but the system could not **start** the process. For example, `CreateProcess` will succeed even if one of the launchee's imports cannot be resolved.

There are probably a dozen suggestions one could make depending on what exactly I hope to accomplish by having launched this process. However, I'm afraid none of those suggestions is likely to be useful because I'm not hoping to acccomplish anything in particular by having launched this process.

One example suggestion might be to call `WaitForSingleObject` against the process handle and then `GetExitCodeProcess`. But I can't wait for the process to exit because it might stick around forever.

Another example suggestion might be to call `WaitForInputIdle`, which would work well if I hoped to communicate with the launchee by means of a window I could reasonably expect the launchee to create. But I don't hope that and I can't reasonably expect that. For all I know, the launchee is a console process and/or will never have a message queue. As well, I can't afford to wait around (with heuristic intent) to find out.

In fact, I can't assume anything about the launchee.

To get a better idea of how I'm thinking here, let's look at the flip side of the issue. If the process doesn't start, I want an error code that tells me how I might advise the user. If the imports all resolved and the main thread realizes it's about to jump into the CRT startup code (or equivalent), and the error code I get back is `ERROR_SUCCESS`, great! But I'm actually disinterested in the launchee and merely wish to provide a good user experience in the launcher.

Oh, and one more thing: I want this to be simple. I don't want to write a debugger. :-)

Ideas?

Comment: for what it's worth, launching with DEBUG_PROCESS is very simple, but may have side-effects you don't want.

Comment: If you want to catch when the process you're launching fails to resolve all its imports, do you also want to catch when it throws an exception and doesn't catch it? What about when it decides to just run off into invalid memory and segfault? Or if it decides to terminate because the command-line arguments were wrong? From a UX point of view, all of those "it didn't work" situations are pretty similar to a non-technical person.

Comment: True, so I guess I should clarify I do want to assume one thing: The process is responsible for reporting its own failures.

Comment: Shouldn't it then be responsible for reporting when a DLL it wants to use can't be found?

Comment: One could certainly argue that, but since import resolution happens before the main thread enters the CRT, and since most code and especially ported code is written without awareness of which symbols will need to be imported and which the linker will take care of, I want to be able to report those failures in the launcher. Basically, most programs think the universe begins with main, and I want to coddle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has gone so long without an answer that I suspect it's safe to conclude that the answer is: "You can't."

Answer (score 1):

> One example suggestion might be to call WaitForSingleObject against the process handle and then GetExitCodeProcess. But I can't wait for the process to exit because it might stick around forever.

Why don't you wait for the process handle for some reasonable time.  If the timer expires before the handle is signaled, you can presume the process is up and running.  If the handle is signaled first, and the exit code is good, then you can presume it ran and completed successfully.

In case you haven't seen it, the CreateProcess vs started problem was mentioned in [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/19/356048.aspx).

Honestly, if you're not willing to accept heuristics (like, "it hasn't ended with a failure code after three seconds, therefore we assume all is well") then you're going to have to write a 'debugger', by which I mean inspect the internals of the launched process.

Comment: Yeah, heuristics are what I'm hoping to avoid. I'll do it if I must -- it's less bad than writing a debugger -- but a real solution would be better.

Comment: You could do something like an AppInit DLL that reports back about every process that launches.  But what is your goal?  What are your conditions for calling a process successful?  Every DLL has loaded?  A DLL could be explicitly loaded at any time, and the app could exit with an error, so reporting back that the implicit DLL loads completed is really only another heuristic.

Comment: I'm happy letting dynamically loaded DLLs fail. What I'm after is simply determining whether the app's perceived universe, which begins on the first line of main (or, if it's crazy, the first constructor of a global object) has come into existence. If the app has had a shot at working, that's enough. If it later fails for any reason, that's fine. That's its own problem.

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of AppInit DLLs until just now. I'm still wrapping my head around them. My first reaction would be to avoid doing something with global scope, but I'll swish the idea  around on my tongue for a while.